# Android java trouble with start new activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

In MainActivity starts another activity via startActivityForResult

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AutorisationForm.class);
intent.putExtra("req", 1);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Method onCreate executes successful, activity displays on the screen and then app crash. Eclipse returns "source not found" error.

How I can solve this problem?

P.S. All activities declared in manifest.

P.P.S All worked successfully before I add a lot of logic in MainActivity. This code and second class hasn't changed.

Comment: Add your logcat output

Comment: Just a note - your haven't spelled "AuthorisationForm" correctly in your code  (you have "AutorisationForm")  - maybe it's not spelled the same in the AndroidManifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Mistake was in `onDestroy()` method in `MainActivity`. In this method app try to save unloaded file. Theme closed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Mufaddal it is what the OP did to solve the problem so it is an answer.

Comment: @Tolyas if this solved your problem then you can accept it as correct. Possibly you could add a little more detail as to *why* it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Undo all changes before adding "a lot of logic in MainActivity."

Add changes one at a time and test in between until you discover problem.

Problem discovered!

Comment: It will be extreme measures. If I won't solve it before Sunday.